# IDA Pro debugging an ARM binary on windows with QEMU

Tags: ida, arm

I have an arm executable which I was debugging with *gdb-multi* and *qemu-arm* on linux, how can I do the same with IDA pro on windows with QEMU, without needing a remote host for "remote debugging" ?